# How does MetaMask populate its Infura enpoints securely?

Tags: web3js, metamask, infura, rpc

As MetaMask uses Infura as one of its node providers, multiple endpoints have to be generated for that purpose. How does MetaMask manage to acquire that many endpoints? And how do they protect their endpoints from being used in other context, knowing that Infura has a certain limit for requests per day?

Answer (score 0):

> How does MetaMask manage to acquire that many endpoints?

I believe their default RPC endpoints are Infura endpoints.

> How do they protect their endpoints from being used in other context, knowing that Infura has a certain limit for requests per day?

I'm not sure exactly how Infura manages request limits, but if you'd like to upgrade your RPC connections, check out this document:

https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/guides/connecting-metamask-to-alchemy

From the doc:

> MetaMask uses a default node provider to display and send transactions for your account. Because the node provider does not allocate dedicated resources to each user, it may be slow sometimes, i.e. for transaction broadcasting.
>
> Alchemy provides a much better experience when it is used as your MetaMask RPC provider. If you'd like to switch this over to Alchemy to be able to see your transactions in your Alchemy dashboard and use Alchemy specific features and tools, this doc will show you how to integrate your MetaMask account in two easy steps.